# Middleman blog extension: Two output variants of same source

Tags: middleman

I want to have a single source folder with articles and generate two or more variants of the output. (For example a print/archive version or a special mobile version for A/B tests with a canonical link to one variant.)

When having a config like this

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = "variant"
  blog.sources = "news/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.layout = "news/variant-layout"
  blog.permalink = "variant/{year}/{title}.html"
  ...
end
...
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.name = "news"
  blog.sources = "news/{year}-{month}-{day}-{title}.html"
  blog.layout = "news/layout"
  blog.permalink = "news/{year}/{title}.html"
  ...
end
```

Note the difference in the `blog.permalink` configuration to generate the URLs.

The layout gets mixed up, links are wrong (always pointing to the versions appearing last in the configuration file) and pages missing.

I added a custom extension to hook into the middleman lifecycle, adding the missing resources to the sitemap. (Which I consider a hack...) At least the missing pages appear after that, but with the wrong layout and links are always pointing to the wrong version.
Trying to `proxy` with a different template seems to be prevented since the blog extension itself generates dynamic proxy pages.
I am currently stuck with middleman 3.4 since the asciidoc extension for middleman 4 is not yet published. Is this a general limitation in middleman that I can not generate multiple variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best course of action is the following:

- upgrade to `gem 'middleman', '~> 4.1.7'`
- use `gem 'middleman-targets'`

You could then configure two build targets: `default` and `variant`, like this:

```
# config.rb

set :target, :default

set :targets, {
  default: {
     layout: 'layout-one',
     build_dir: 'build/default',
     target_specific_config: 'foo',
     features : {
        feature_one: true 
     }  
  },
  variant: {
     layout: 'layout-two',
     build_dir: 'build/variant',
     target_specific_config: 'bar',
     features : {
        feature_one: false 
     }  
  }
```

Now you should be able to switch complete layouts like this:

```
# layout.erb

<% wrap_layout(target_value(:layout)) do %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can use feature flags or specific config values in the individual pages, like so:

```
# page.erb

<% if target_feature?(:feature_one) %>
  <p>Feature One Is ON</p>
  <p>Value is: <%= target_value(:target_specific_config) %>
<% else %>
  <p>Feature One Is OFF</p>
  <p>Value is: <%= target_value(:target_specific_config) %>
<% end %>
```

Documentation is a little scarce at the moment, so it is probably best to read the 'helpers' part of the source code here: https://github.com/middlemac/middleman-targets/blob/master/lib/middleman-targets/extension.rb